# Is the alignment incorrect on the tag badge congratulations message?

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badges

The congratulations message and icons which are displayed when I receive a new tag badge are top-left aligned in the Summary box on my profile page.

Is this how it's supposed to look?

[image: Screenshot of "Congratulations! You've earned Laravel" bronze tag badge message on profile page]

Comment: Some annotation of the screenshot, like arrows and text, would be helpful.